# How to Use Segue when UICollectionViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass in which each of table cell contains a `UICollectionView` with multiple `UIcollectionViewCell`s.

I need, when any `collectionViewCell` is being clicked a new viewController has to open.

I have overridden below method,

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As I have implemented whole collectionView in UITableViewCell subclass so I am unable to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self];`

I have tried `prepareForSegue` in the same class but it loads new viewController before `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your UITableViewCell subclass

```
@protocol MyUITableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)selectedCell;
@end


@interface MyUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell
 ....
 ....
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<MyUITableViewCellDelegate>delegate;
 ..
 ..
@end
```

In your view controller, for each UITableViewCell set

```
cell.delegate = self;
```

For your SomeViewController.m file

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<MyUITableViewCellDelegate>{
.....
}

@end

@implementation SomeViewController
.....
...... 
-(void)selectedCell{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self];// The segue with identifier 'NewViewController' should be from SomeViewController to the desired view controller.

}
.....
@end
```

And call selectedCell like this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   [self.delegate selectedCell];
}
```

I think this will solve your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    YourViewController *newView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: `navigationController` property is not available in `UITableViewCell` subclass

Comment: In AppDelegate

// AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;

In didFinishLaunching  

[window setRootViewController:navController];

And use this 
UINavigationController *navController = window.rootViewController;

and use navController in your tableview cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self];` from inside `UITableViewCell` which seems be the case for you, as `performSegueWithIdentifier` is `UIViewController` method, so logically you need to call this function in UIViewController.

You need to setup Protocol and call the fire the method from inside the `UITableViewCell` to `UIViewController`, something like this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    [self.delegate cellDidSelect:indexPath];
}
```

And in `UIViewController` where you have `UITableView` just handle

```
-(void)cellDidSelect:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self];
}
```

Or, use the UIViewController reference as property in the UITableViewCell, and call directly like

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        [self.parentContoller performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController" sender:self.parentContoller];
    }
```

Hope it helps you. Cheers.

Comment: I am getting this error
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<MainViewController: 0xxxxxxxx>) has no segue with identifier 'NewViewController''`  when I call it from UIViewController. As identifier is properly added and in working in other viewControllers